# subquery doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine2, dql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT * FROM vocabulary.word
    WHERE movie_id = (select movie_id from vocabulary.word order by id desc LIMIT 1)
    AND season = (select season from vocabulary.word order by id desc LIMIT 1)
    AND episode = (select episode from vocabulary.word order by id desc LIMIT 1)
```

не могу переписать на подзапрос в доктрине
так не работает

```
       $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('w1')
        ->select([
            'w1.movie',
            'w1.season',
            'w1.episode'
        ])
        ->orderBy('w1.id', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
    ;

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('w')
        ->select([
            'w.name as word',
            'w.translation as translation',
            'm.name as movie',
            'w.season as season',
            'w.episode as episode',
        ])
        ->leftJoin('w.movie', 'm')
        ->where($query->expr()->eq('m.movie', $query->getDQL()))
        ->andWhere($query->expr()->eq('w.season', $query->getDQL()))
        ->where($query->expr()->eq('w.episode', $query->getDQL()))
        ->orderBy('RAND()')
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

[Syntax Error] line 0, col 172: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'
вот такая ошибка вылетает с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы в проверке использовать подзапросы, необходимо, чтобы подзапрос возвращал одно поле. А у вас подзапрос возвращает 3. В вашем случае придется сделать 3 разных подзапроса для `movie`,`season`,`episode`.

Или вообще не связываться с подзапросами, а выполнить один запрос, а во второй подставить конкретные значения `movie`,`season`,`episode`

Если для подзапроса используется проверка `eq`, то DQL подзапроса надо внести в скобки `'('.$movieQuery->getDQL().')'`

```
$movieQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('w1')
    ->select('w1.movie')
    ->orderBy('w1.id', 'DESC')
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getQuery();
$seasonQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('w1')
    ->select('w1.season')
    ->orderBy('w1.id', 'DESC')
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getQuery();
$episodeQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('w1')
    ->select('w1.episode')
    ->orderBy('w1.id', 'DESC')
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getQuery();

return $this->createQueryBuilder('w')
    ->select([
        'w.name as word',
        'w.translation as translation',
        'm.name as movie',
        'w.season as season',
        'w.episode as episode',
    ])
    ->leftJoin('w.movie', 'm')
    ->where($query->expr()->eq('m.movie', '('.$movieQuery->getDQL().')'))
    ->andWhere($query->expr()->eq('w.season', '('.$seasonQuery->getDQL().')'))
    ->where($query->expr()->eq('w.episode', '('.$episodeQuery->getDQL().')'))
    ->orderBy('RAND()')
    ->setMaxResults($limit)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: "Или вообще не связываться с подзапросами, а выполнить один запрос, а во второй подставить конкретные значения movie,season,episode"

дело в том что я не могу подставить конкретный значения

Comment: я не думаю что можно это сделать одним запросом

Comment: У вас в SQL запросе в начале все правильно сделано. Сделайте 3 разных query для подзапросов. И подставьте их DQL в итоговый

Comment: а, ну вот и полный запрос вам в ответе дали

Comment: Дополнил ответ кодом

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909759/error-%D0%B2-subquery-doctrine2

Comment: Еще дополнил по поводу возникающей ошибки. Поскольку используется eq, то надо обрамлять скобками. in добавит скобки сам

Comment: спасибо, но и это решение мне не подходит поскольку в доктрине нельзя писать limit в nested queries. Но вы ответили на мой вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте переписать запрос на

```
SELECT w.* 
FROM vocabulary.word w,
     ( select movie_id 
       from vocabulary.word  
       order by id desc LIMIT 1) sq1,
     ( select season  
       from vocabulary.word  
       order by id desc LIMIT 1) sq2,
     ( select episode  
       from vocabulary.word  
       order by id desc LIMIT 1) sq3
WHERE w.movie_id = sq1.movie_id 
  AND w.season = sq2.season 
  AND w.episode = sq3.episode
```

Возможно, в такой форме будет проще.

Comment: вы не могли бы показать как это написать через query builder?

Comment: @gudfar Про doctrine знаю только, что оно существует.

Comment: ахах, я понял))